# Struct referencing in lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, struct

I'm having trouble setting the values in a struct using a lambda expression referencing local values in the function in which the lambda expression is defined. If I understand it correctly, the struct is passed by value in the lambda function, but I'd like it to pass by reference. I do not know how to do it.

Test code:

```
public struct partialData
{
    public int foo;
}
public struct futureData
{
    public int bar;
}

// if you change this to a class, everything works as desired.
public struct someStruct 
{
    public partialData pd;
    public futureData fd;
}
class Apple
{
    private Action<object> toBeSet;
    public someStruct makeStruct(partialData pd)
    {
        someStruct ss = new someStruct();
        ss.pd = pd;

        toBeSet = new Action<object>(
             (futureValue) => ss.fd = (futureData)futureValue
        );
        return ss;
    }
    public void futureSet(futureData fd)
    {
        toBeSet.Invoke(fd);
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        partialData pd;
        pd.foo = 1;
        futureData fd;
        fd.bar = 2;
        Apple ap=new Apple();
        someStruct ss= ap.makeStruct(pd);
        ap.futureSet(fd);
        // I'd like it to be 1,2, it results in 1,0
        Console.WriteLine("foo is: "+ss.pd.foo + ", bar is: "+ss.fd.bar);
        Console.In.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Notes:
The structures are written by someone else (and are used for interop), I cannot change them to classes. I like my current design, so I'm hoping for a way to keep this design but just have the struct in the Action behave as a class. Another reason to not change to classes is that some of the structs are nested deeply and would take more effort to update than I think should be necessary.

Comment: I don't suppose boxing it into as `Object` type then casting it back in the lambda would work, would it? (if not ugly)

Comment: Actually, wait a second, won't your `makeStruct` method essentially return a copy of your "someStruct ss" anyway?  So even if you could have your lambda target that actual "ss" instance declared in the method, wouldn't your caller of makeStruct receive a copy and not the original anyway? (could be solved with a `ref` parameter though)

Comment: Using ref didn't fix it, but that was a problem I hadn't thought about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass structure by reference, then you need your own delegate type with `ref` parameter (which is not in the set of standard `Action<>` and `Func<>`).

Also, when using lambdas, compiler can't infer types of `ref` and `out` parameters, so, you have to declare them explicitly or use good old anonymous delegates syntax (which looks very similar to lambdas with declared types):

```
struct S
{
    public int f;
}

delegate void DoDelegate(ref S s);

public static void M()
{
    var s = new S();

    DoDelegate delegate2 = (ref S st) => st.f = 5;
    DoDelegate delegate1 = delegate(ref S st) { st.f = 10; };

    delegate1.Invoke(ref s);
    delegate2.Invoke(ref s);
}
```

Comment: It's too bad there's no real language or framework support for collections to expose themselves to such methods.  Mutable structs are much safer data holders than mutable classes, and are often much more convenient than immutable types, but the syntax required for an array-like collection to allow a consumer to modify a field of a struct contained therein is pretty hideous.

Comment: BTW, the linked question is different, since it relates to the inability of lambda functions to capture `ref` or `out` parameters of the surrounding function, as opposed to a restriction on a lambda function's own parameters.

Comment: @supercat: completely disagree about safety of mutable structs. I think, structs must be only immutable. But +1 about linked question, my answer had contained an inexactitude. Updated the answer, thanks!

Comment: @Dennis: There are some problems with .net's support of mutable structs, to be sure, but they are far safer than mutable classes.  In many cases, the ideal way of transporting data may be to use a mutable class to construct an instance, and then either copy the data to an immutable class or construct a immutable wrapper.  Unfortunately, there's no convenient way to create parallel mutable and immutable classes with the same properties. Structures with exposed mutable fields are almost as good, since protecting a struct's storage location against mutation will protect the fields of that struct.

Answer (score 2):

Put the struct in a holder class and pass around an instance of the holder class.

```
public class SomeStructHolder
{
    public someStruct theStruct;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use a property though.  Accessing the getter of `theStruct` will always return a copy of the struct making modification of its `fd` field thrown away.

Comment: Good answer, I just don't want to be doing all the nested struct stuff -- I think delegate "feels" like the answer I'm looking for -- to explain why I changed the accepted answer.